# Laravel & JQuery: Display mysql row data if ID is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel, autocomplete

I have manage to get autocomplete data with typeahead search tutorial where I change in a way that now searching by three columns instead of one. So, when I start typing in search field autocomplete display:

Street from-to

and based on that I supposed to display other data from that ID (ID of that row but ID is not displayed).

You can see how it looks in my controller:

```
public function ajaxData(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('query', '');

    $streets = Street::select('id', 'name')
      ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
      ->get();

    $results = array();

    foreach($streets as $sn) {
        $street_numbers = StreetNumber::select('from', 'to')
          ->where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
          ->where('street_id', $sn->id)
          ->get();

          foreach($street_numbers as $st) {
              $data = array(
                'name' => $sn->name." ".$st->from."-".$st->to
              );
              $results[] = $data;
          }
    }

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

In view I supposed to select from autocomplete and when I click on submit it should display data like town, settlement etc...

But, if I try to use $street_numbers variable it shows me error:
(2/2) ErrorException
Undefined variable: street_numbers

In view beside field I have JQuery from typeahed tutorial:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'add.index', 'method'=>'GET']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Search</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="input-group">
                  {!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Street from - to','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-default']) !!}
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "{{ route('autocomplete.ajax') }}";
    $('#search_text').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get(url, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm very stuck on this one and don't know how to start from here because in JS or JQuery I'm a beginner.

Before ajaxData() function I have index() function and there I have:

```
return view('members.index', compact('towns', 'user', 'activist', 'capillary'));
```

So there is my view.

I'm trying to use $street_numbers variable in view like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('', 'Settlement') !!}
    {!! Form::select('', [$street_numbers? $street_numbers->settlement->name : null => $street_numbers? $street_numbers->settlement->name : null], null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'readonly']) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use `$street_numbers`? Where are you getting this error exactly?

Comment: I edited first question with more details so you can see where I trying to use $street_numbers...

Comment: The blade template where you use `$street_numbers`, is that in `members.index` or a different view, if different, how are you initializing that view?

Comment: I have index() function before ajaxData() function where I returned view('members.index', compact('street_numbers'));

Comment: Then that is the reason for the error. You create `$street_numbers` *inside ajaxData*, the variable only exists inside that function, you wont be able to access it inside your `index` function. Changing `$street_numbers ?` to `isset($street_numbers) ?` will stop the error but Im still not sure that will give you the expected results. ie it looks like $street_numbers will always be unset in that context

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded and I want to share with others in case somebody needs it:

In submit button I placed 'id'=>'get_cust_data' and then I made separate .js file where I pull information from autocomplete search field when it's submitted.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#get_cust_data').click(function(){
      var st = $.trim($("#search_text").val());
      get_cust_data(st);
  });
});
```

In controller I get data with explode function because, as I said in first post I have street-from-to from database, not just one data. In further codes you will see how I get ID from street and then object which I use to get other info from same row like settlement, electorUnit and so...

```
public function get_cust_data(Request $reques)
{
    $arr = explode("-", $reques->st);
    $street = $arr[0];
    $from = $arr[1];
    $to = $arr[2];

    // Street ID
    $street_id = Street::select('id')
      ->where('name', $street)
      ->first()->id;

    // Object
    $street_data = StreetNumber::select('*')
      ->where('street_id',$street_id)
      ->where('from', $from)
      ->where('to', $to)
      ->get();

    $result = array();

    // Settlement ID
    $settlement_id = $street_data[0]->settlement_id;
    $result['settlement_id'] = $settlement_id;

    // Settlement Name
    $settl_data = Settlement::select('name')
      ->where('id',$settlement_id)
      ->get();

    // ElectoralUnit ID
    $electoral_unit_id = $street_data[0]->electoral_unit_id;
    $result['electoral_unit_id'] = $electoral_unit_id;

    // ElectoralUnit Name
    $el_unit_data = ElectoralUnit::select('name')
      ->where('id',$electoral_unit_id)
      ->get();

    // ElectoralUnitNumber
    $el_unit_number_data = ElectoralUnit::select('electoral_unit_number')
      ->where('id',$electoral_unit_id)
      ->get();

    $result['s_name'] = $settl_data[0]->name;
    $result['e_name'] = $el_unit_data[0]->name;
    $result['e_n_name'] = $el_unit_number_data[0]->electoral_unit_number;
    $result['street'] = $street;
    $result['str_id'] = $street_id;

    return response()->json(json_encode($result));
}
```

Then in the sam JS file, which is connected in header to view, I put another function that I googled and can't explain completely how it works, but that function forwarding variables from controller through view with fields ID-s like this:

```
function get_cust_data(street_data){
  var method_url= "/get_cust_data";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      url: method_url,
      cache: false,
      data:{ st:street_data},
      async: true,
      success: function(response){
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        // console.log(data.id);
        $('#street').append("<option value='"+data.street+"'>"+data.street+"</option>");
        $('#settlement_id').append("<option value="+data.settlement_id+">"+data.s_name+"</option>");
        $('#electoral_unit').append("<option value='"+data.e_name+"'>"+data.e_name+"</option>");
        $('#electoral_unit_number').append("<option value="+data.electoral_unit_id+">"+data.e_n_name+"</option>");
        // console.log(data.message);
      }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

    });
}
```

I hope that at least I explained a bit and will help somebody. Cheers!